# Can't launch Postman from terminal in 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I downloaded Postman from https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/ and extracted it. But I can't execute it from terminal and got Javascript error. Any idea?

```
ab-ubuntu@sithu:/opt/Postman$ ./Postman
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'circular-json'
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/opt/Postman/app/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/Postman/app/resources/app/main.js:7:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/Postman/app/resources/app/main.js:733:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
```

Comment: This link makes me download "Postman Canary", you downloaded 64 bits (PostmanCanary-linux-x64-7.11.0-canary01.tar.gz) ?

Comment: No, it is `Postman-linux-x64-7.10.0.tar.gz`

Comment: you tried PostmanCanary-linux-x64-7.11.0-canary01.tar.gz?